# WireMock keep-alive

Tags: keep-alive, wiremock

I am want to know whether WireMock supports keep-alive by default or I need to set it explicitly somewhere.

I have setup a basic WireMock standalone which accepts request and generates a json payload. However when I curl -v the service I do not see the Connection: keep-alive header generated.

Also when I make a call to the mock service using the apache benchmark tool with -k option I do see lot of connections getting created and destroyed which means wiremock by default is not supporting the keep-alive.

I assume there must be something on the WireMock server to tell it to support persistent connections by default?

Regards,
Adi

Comment: Did you found solution?

Answer (score 0):

You could have that header returned by updating your mapping as such:

`"response": { "headers": { "Content-Type": "application/json" }`

This however *doesn't* mean that it's a persistent connection and persistent connections are supported on WireMock.  There is a "persistent" option for mappings, but per the WireMock docs, it's:

> *Indicates that the stub mapping should be persisted immediately on create/update/delete and survive resets to default.*

[https://wiremock.org/docs/api/#tag/Stub-Mappings/paths/~1__admin~1mappings/get](https://wiremock.org/docs/api/#tag/Stub-Mappings/paths/%7E1__admin%7E1mappings/get)